# Input numeric text for # loops

Tags: php, for-loop, iteration, break

My goal is to put some numeric text in a text box, for example, if I entered "3", it will come out:

Hello 1

Hello 2

Hello 3

My problem is that it keeps going until the loop entirely finishes (well 74 times), and not adhere to the entered value, and stop at 3 or some digit that I enter.

```
<div class="Container">
        <h2>Hello Page</h2><hr>
        <form>
            <p>Enter a number:</p>
            <input type="text" name="number">
            <input type="submit" value="Enter">
        </form>

        <?php
        $digit = $_GET['number'];

        if (empty($digit))
            $digit= "";
        elseif (!empty($digit)) {

            for ($digit= 1; $digit< 75; $digit++) {
                if ($digit== TRUE) {
                    echo 'Hello ' . $digit. '<br>';

                } elseif ($digit== $digit) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        ?>

    </div>
```

Comment: Please, don't use **URGENT** in the question title.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Question you asked is programming basics. Maybe start from some tutorial, read some book first.

Comment: I apologize for that mistake

Comment: I have a book on PHP, been working on it for days now and it just hasn't been working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your $digit variable is the maximum, use it that way.
Change your for loop in this

```
for ($x= 1; $x <= $digit; $x++) {
    echo 'Hello ' . $x. '<br />';
}
```

Then you will get what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Method 1.

```
for($i=0;$i<$_GET['number'];$i++) {
  echo "Hello {$i}<br/>";
}
```

Method 2.

```
$i = 0;
while($i < $_GET['number'])
  echo "Hello {$i}<br/>";
  $i++;
}
```

Method 3.

```
$i = 0;
while(true) {
  if($i >= $_GET['number']) break;
  echo "Hello {$i}<br/>";
  $i++;     
}
```

Method 4.

```
do {
  echo "Hello {$i}<br/>";
  $i++;
} while($i < $_GET['number']);
```

Comment: Oh my god, thank you so much. By the way to people who came on here to review my question, thanks. I never knew that there was so many people active on this site! This site rocks!! xD

Comment: @user1995608 still, this is php/any language basics maybe try to use read some books/try to do things by yourself instead of asking about basic stuff

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that you are using $digit as the variable receiving your form input, AND as your incrementor variable in your loop.  So basically you are overwriting your inputted value.  So basically you need to use 2 variables, not 1.

Comment: wow..a negative vote for pointing out the problem? probably from one of you other members who downvoted the question itself and you just mad because i'm trying to help instead of point out his failures in posting questions..

Comment: very often behaviour at SO, sometimes i would like to see names of downvoters